# Google Fonts not working on iphone device

Tags: html, css, iphone, fonts

I can't get the Oswald font (Google Font) to display correctly on iphone devices.

Here is a test page: 
http://kiny.linkedupradio.com/test-font.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see it fine on ios8. But I've had trouble with cross browser compatibility with google fonts in the past. I suggest you download the font and upload it to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator so you get versions for most browsers you are going to need.